# Reaction mechanism of rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, phenols, rearrangements

I am currently studying for my organic chemistry exam, but there is one problem I do not understand. Unfortunately, I do not have any solutions.

See image for the problem.

[image]

My first thought was the Dienone-phenol-rearrangement. But in order to do so, I need to add the alkyl substituent and I need a dienone. So can I deprotonate the phenol using potassium carbonate? (Or is it too weak as a base? The pKa of bicarbonate is around 10, so maybe it is too weak) But if it is possible, then the free electron pair of the oxygen can form a ketone... I could then use the alkene with a chloride substituent, so that the aromatic ring can attack it. Then I would have the dienone. But with the Dienone-phenol-rearrangement, the alkyl substituent can only move by one carbon-atom in the ring...

Is my thought process wrong? Can you please help me?

I did not have any lectures on rearrangement reactions, I had to learn them by myself, but by now, I have not found any similar reactions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first reaction is *O*-alkylation of *p*-cresol to give a 4-methylphenyl allyl ether derivative **3**. The reagent in the first box should be 1-bromo-3-methylbut-2-ene (**1**; see the top box in the picture), which would undergo $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction with phenolic anion (**2**) in refluxing acetone. Note that potassium carbonate is a strong enough base to complete this reaction (this is surely a strong base than potassium bicarbonate).

[image: Claisen Rearrangement]

The product **3** from alkylation would undergo Claisen rearrangement upon heating to give final alkylated cresol **4** in solvent-free condition. Remember, Claisen found his famous rearrangement first in solvent-free conditions, while he was trying to find the melting point of newly synthesized naphthyl allyl ether! (Picture is from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3873100/ and modified accordingly)

Answer (score 8):

Potassium carbonate is a perfectly good base for the alkylation of phenol ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 10$) with a good electrophile, in this case 3,3-dimethylallylbromide. The reaction you are looking for is Claisen rearrangement which proceeds by a 3,3-sigmatropic rearrangement [mechanism](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/claisen-rearrangement.shtm).

[image: Claisen rearrangement]
Image from [ref 1](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/claisen-rearrangement.shtm)

Answer (score 4):

The first step is nucleophilic substitution.

> [It is possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allylic_rearrangement) for nucleophile to attack directly at the allylic position, displacing the leaving group in a single step, in a process referred to as $\mathrm{S_N2'}$ substitution. This is likely in cases when the allyl compound is unhindered, and a strong nucleophile is used. The products will be similar to those seen with $\mathrm{S_N1'}$ substitution. Thus reaction of 1-chloro-2-butene with sodium hydroxide gives a mixture of 2-buten-1-ol and 3-buten-2-ol:

[image: Allyl halide reaction with NaOH]

## Step 1: Williamson Ether synthesis

- *para*-Cresol reacts with 3,3-dimethylallylbromide to give **1** and **2** using potassium carbonate in acetone as shown below.

[image: Allyl phenyl ether preparation]

## Step 2: 3,3-Sigmatropic rearrangement (Aromatic Claisen rearrangement)

- Compounds **1** and **2** undergo 3,3-sigmatropic rearrangement (Aromatic Claisen rearrangement)${^1}$. Compound **1** gives **3** via sigmatropic shift followed by tautomerism to give **4** (as shown below).

Similarly, **2** gives **5** via sigmatropic shift followed by tautomerism to give **6** (as shown below).

[image: 3,3-sigmatropic rearrangement-1]

[image: 3,3-sigmatropic rearrangement-2]

## Net reaction

As per the question given, the following is the scheme.

[image: Reaction Scheme]

**References**

${^1}$:https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3873100/
${^2}$:https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/Chapter_18%3A_Ethers_and_Epoxides%3B_Thiols_and_Sulfides/18.04_Reactions_of_Ethers_-_Claisen_Rearrangement

${^3}$:J. Am. Chem. Soc.19891112511-519 Publication Date:January 1, 1989
https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00184a018